# Colorear borde de imagen de acuerdo a un numero "X" POWERPOINT VBA

Tags: vba

Necesito realizar una macro que me coloree el borde de una imagen de acuerdo a un numero "X" que esta en la misma presentacion.

Ejemplo si tengo el numero 1 en la diapositiva, el borde de la imagen se coloree de color rojo, si tengo un numero 2, se coloree el borde de color verde.

Lo que tengo hasta el momento es este codigo, que inserta una imagen en una diapositiva X, me colorea el borde negro, y envia la imagen al fondo.

```
 'imagen1'

Set imagen1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(3)
Set pic = imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:="E:\1.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=10, Top:=50, Width:=220, Height:=128)
    
    With pic
    
.Line.Weight = 1
.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Selecionar el color
.ZOrder (msoSendToBack)

    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideNumber devuelve el número de la diapositiva, de modo que si quieres que un color RGB (rojo, verde, azul) sea rojo se asigna 255 al rojo:

```
 If ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideNumber = 1 Then
    pic.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' color rojo
 End If
```